# What does UNION ALL do here in this piece of SQL recursion code?

Tags: sql

```
WITH counting_numbers as ( 
    SELECT 
        -- Initialize number
        1 AS number
    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        -- Increment number by 1
        number+1 
    FROM counting_numbers
    -- Set the termination condition
    WHERE number < 50)
```

If I am not mistaken, each loop yields 2 outputs. If so, UNION ALL combines them to be one?

Answer (score 2):

This is a recursive CTE.  The first select is the base case, which seeds the `number` column with a value of 1.  The recursive select, which occurs after the `UNION ALL`, selects 1 plus whatever previous value were in `number` (whose value would start at 1).  The database will populate the CTE using the recursive select until the `WHERE` clause fails, which would happen when `number` reaches a value of 50.

Follow the link below for a running demo in Postgres.

### Demo

Comment: can I remove ALL?

Comment: @ZZZ Actually, yes, you should be able to do that, because each record in the CTE should have a unique `number` value, and therefore there should be no duplicates.

Comment: @zzz . . . You do not want to remove the `ALL`.  `UNION` -- without `ALL` -- incurs overhead to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

In a Common table expression, there are two parts:

- Anchor part (only one time executed. at the very beginning. It cannot refer to CTE in the query definition)
- Recursive part(Repeatedly executed based on the number of levels in hierarchy. It can refer to CTE in the query definition.)

In addition, UNION ALL is for concatenation (It combines anchor part resultset with recursive part result)

[Common Table Expression msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
      ;WITH counting_numbers as ( 
                SELECT 
                    -- Initialize number, Anchor part 
                    1 AS number
                UNION ALL    
            SELECT 
                -- Increment number by 1, Recursive part. It can refer to CTE 
                number+1 
            FROM counting_numbers
            -- Set the termination condition
            WHERE number < 50)
```

Comment: can you specify the output of first 3 loops? My understanding is you have 1,2 for loop1 and 1,2,3 for loop 2 and 1,2,3,4 for loop 3 and so on

Comment: first it is anchor: 1, second it is recursive: 1,2, third it is recursive: 1,2,3... It goes upto 1,2,3... 50

Comment: ```sql   
WITH calculate_potencies (step, result) AS (
    SELECT 
    -- Initialize step and result
    1 as step,
    1 as result
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT 
    step + 1,
    -- Add the POWER calculation to the result
    result + POWER(step + 1, step + 1)
    FROM calculate_potencies
    WHERE step < 9)
```

Comment: It is calculating step from 1 to 9 as recursive: ```1 1
2 5
3 32
4 288
5 3413
6 50069
7 873612
8 17650828
9 405071317```